# Problems using HibernateTemplate: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am quite new in Spring world and I am going crazy trying to integrate Hibernate in Spring application using **HibernateTemplate** abstract support class

I have the following class to persist on database table:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int pid;

private String firstname;

private String lastname;

public int getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(int pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
}
```

Next to it I have create an interface named **PersonDAO** in wich I only define my CRUD method.
So I have implement this interface by a class named **PersonDAOImpl** that also extend the Spring abstract class **HibernateTemplate**:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class PersonDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements PersonDAO{


public void addPerson(Person p) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(p);

}

public Person getById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public List<Person> getPersonsList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void delete(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void update(Person person) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   

}
```

(at the moment I am trying to implement only the addPerson() method)

Then I have create a main class to test the operation of insert a new object into the database table:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAO;
import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    System.out.println("Contesto recuperato: " + context);

    Person persona1 = new Person();

    persona1.setFirstname("Pippo");
    persona1.setLastname("Blabla");

    System.out.println("Creato persona1: " + persona1);

    PersonDAO dao = (PersonDAO) context.getBean("personDAOImpl");

    System.out.println("Creato dao object: " + dao);

    dao.addPerson(persona1);

    System.out.println("persona1 salvata nel database");
}

}
```

As you can see the **PersonDAOImpl** class **extends HibernateTemplate** so I think that it have to contain the operation of setting of the sessionFactory...

The problem is that when I try to run this MainApp class I obtain the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:323)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.getSession(HibernateTemplate.java:457)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:392)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
    at org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl.addPerson(PersonDAOImpl.java:12)
    at org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:26)
```

Why I have this problem? how can I solve it?

To be complete I also insert my **pom.xml** containing my dependencies list:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.andrea.myexample</groupId>
<artifactId>HibernateOnSpring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>HibernateOnSpring</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dipendenze di Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>   <!-- Usata da Hibernate 4 per LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dipendenze per AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dipendenze per Persistence Managment -->

    <dependency>    <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>    <!-- Hibernate -->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: `HibernateTemplate` is quite old and Hibernate 4.x doesn't support it anymore. Don't use it.

Comment: ok, and what I have to use in its place?

Comment: You should be using `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` instead (if you're using Hibernate), you may better deal with `EntityManager` though.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using Springs Hibernate4 support

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
```

More details here:
http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/

Comment: There is no `hibernate4.support.HiberbateDaoSupport`

Comment: HiberbateDaoSupport deprecated since version 3 and version 4 it is removed

Answer (score 1):

Since `HibernateTemplate` is no longer supported in Hibernate 4.x and my current project is riddled with the use of `HibernateTemplate` I've opted to create and use my own custom `HibernateTemplate`.

Rather than extending `HibernateDaoSupport` I just added a `getHibernateTemplate()` method to my DAO.  In my custom `HibernateTemplate` I then use the `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` to perform the same operations.